# Installing WordNet on Linux (Ubuntu trusty)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, configure, wordnet, multiple-makefiles

I am trying to install [WordNet-3.0](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/current-version/) on Ubuntu trusty.

When I ran configure script, I got:

```
checking for Tcl configuration... configure: WARNING: Can't find Tcl 
configuration definitions
```

It's a warning, but still, configuration stopped without creating makefiles.

So I [downloaded](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) and installed tcl8.6.1, then ran the configure script again, but I got:

```
checking for Tcl configuration... found /usr/local/lib/tclConfig.sh
checking for Tk configuration... configure: WARNING: Can't find Tk 
configuration definitions
```

So I [downloaded](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html) and installed tk8.6.1, then ran the configure script again, but the warning message persisted.

I found `tkConfig.sh` in `~/Downloads/tk8.6.1/unix/`, so I copied it to /usr/local/lib, ran the script again, but I got:

```
checking for Tcl configuration... found /usr/local/lib/tclConfig.sh
checking for Tk configuration... found /usr/local/lib/tkConfig.sh
checking for existence of /usr/local/lib/tclConfig.sh... loading
checking for existence of /usr/local/lib/tkConfig.sh... loading
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: WARNING:  'Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
config.status: creating dict/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/html/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/man/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/pdf/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/ps/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `include/tk/Makefile.in'
```

What shall I do? The configure script is a daunting 5755 lines long, I dare not tinker with it...

Comment: I tried `sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/tk8.6` followed by `sudo cp ~/Downloads/tk8.6.1/unix/* /usr/local/lib/tk8.6/` but the script still can't find `include/tk/Makefile.in`...

Comment: I suppose `'Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting` is a clue, but I have no idea what that means

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Was there a reason you tried to install tcl/tk from source? My suggestion would be to delete the manually installed tk and tcl packages (hunt under `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/include`), then use the Ubuntu package manager to install "tk": http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/tk

"tk" has a dependency on "tcl", so it will install that automatically for you, as well as any other dependencies you need.

Then if that still fails, one idea is to install "tk-dev" (which has a dependency on tcl-dev). The "-dev" versions of packages contain all the headers, makefiles, etc, etc.

Comment: if the user is not the root and he can't use package manager on linux, what is the solution?

Comment: @ChediBechikh I'd suggest asking the system administrator to install it, or use a different computer where you do have root. (Or if you just need the data, and not the interface that tcl/tk supplies, you could parse the files manually. Or use another interface to the data, e.g. Python's NLTK.)

Comment: i tested with cpanm Tk, also i tested toinstall it after downloading it but it genrate always **! The distribution doesn't have a proper Makefile.PL/Build.PL ** also if i want to unpack the gz.tar, it generate an error

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. To solve it:

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```